# Why does my cat insistently meow at me when I shower?

Tags: cats, behavior

When I shower, my cat has this unusual habit. She meows at me insistently and repeatedly, and looks at me with wide eyes. I want to mention that I do not keep her in the bathroom against her will. I just leave the door open and she just walks in and starts meowing at me.

Do you know why she is showing this kind of behaviour?

Comment: You're covered in water. IT'S A PERFECT TIME TO PANIC!

Comment: Consider yourself fortunate. One of ours gets in the shower WITH us. He sits and tries to catch the drops from the shower, then play wrestles with us when we dry him.

Comment: You are acting crazy!

Comment: This actually isn't uncommon behavior in cats.

Comment: "Don't play with that; play with cat!"

Comment: Since I can't explain why I meow at my cat -- except that it amuses me and gets a response -- i don't really expect her comments to me to be much more meaningful.

Comment: Did you tried to brush it with your wet hands? I do that to my cats and they love it, they come everytime I finish the shower so they can be brushed, they also get into the bathtub for play with the water drops and drink warm water.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, don't worry, this behavior is entirely normal thing that many cats do. I once visited a friend of mine and she warned me that her cat would visit me on the bathtub ledge between the two shower curtains during my shower. He did, but didn't talk to me, so I was super startled to see him there when I pulled back the curtain!

There are actually a couple of reasons she could be exhibiting this behavior, or it could be a combination of multiple reasons.

If your cat normally follows you around the house, this is just a normal part of her keeping tabs on you. As Dan S says, she wants to join you but doesn't want to get wet, so she's telling you to get out of there.

Another possibility is that if you coo at her and give her attention (verbal, eye contact, etc), she's looking for that attention and knows if she yells at you long enough, you'll give it to her.

Cats are also creatures of habit. If you get up in the morning and immediately jump in the shower and get dressed before heading downstairs to feed her (or whatever), then she's trying to rush you through your morning routine and get to the part where you feed her faster.

If this behavior is bothering you, the best thing to do is close the door so she can't come in, or ignore her when she does talk to you in the shower. We broke one cat of the habit by switching to an opaque shower curtain so she couldn't see us anymore (and ignoring her cries), so that's another option.

Answer (score 11):

One of my cats does this. Cats rely heavily on smell to identify each other and people so I hypothesize she can't smell me (due to soap and water) and becomes worried and vocalizes a crying/upset type meow.

She continues meowing until I pet her profusely when I get out.  So the behavior could also all be her way of getting me to pet her profusely.

We don't smell like we normally do when we are freshly cleaned and covered with perfumes from soap so the cat may feel they need to do something about it. Cats spend a lot of time scenting things, each other, and us, to identify things as their property or as something familiar and accepted. The behavior could be to ensure she has scented me and I her which is highly important in cat socialization.

Conversely, humans are mostly visually-oriented animals so imagine if your significant other stepped out of the shower and looked different and not themselves somehow. You might go over and investigate and try to correct their appearance.

Also this same cat of mine likes freshly laundered things (like laying in a laundry basket with clean clothes) or freshly cleaned counter tops (even with bleach). Maybe it also has something to do with you being freshly laundered.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't worry about it.  Your cat might simply be confused about what you're up to and wanting to join you but not get wet.  My cats often want to join me in the bathroom but I never let them, and they sometimes are very curious / insistent when I am there.

Answer (score 4):

When we take showers, we "disappear" behind the shower curtain or doors. For cats that need more attention and reassurance than average, this can be a little upsetting for them. My cat is an Egyptian Mau, so he has to be involved in my bathroom activities, and he knows my routines. So when I carry my bath towel into the bathroom, he sits outside the bathroom door and howls, before I even turn the shower on.

But I think it's a bit of a game for him too. Because when I'm out of the shower and walk across my apartment, he chases me and bites my calves. He'll stop chasing me if I pick up one of his toys and toss it for him, like I've satisfied his wishes.

Answer (score 4):

One of my cats in particular (my pride and joy,  who is ALWAYS on my lap, grooms me, consistently runs to get ahead of me just so she can flop on her back and present me her belly, comes every time I call her, and also plays fetch) does this every time I shower. And because of the way she reacts two different things I have done while in the shower I'm pretty sure I have the answer as to why they meow while you're in there. All my cats are so used to me being around them all the time that I believe she just wants reassurance that I'm still there even though she can't see me. You learn to recognize the emotion behind different meows. The shower meows always sound very nervous like she's frightened. Usually takes 3 or 4 times of me poking my head out, petting her, and reassuring her that I'm still there before she calms down and stops.

Answer (score 2):

My kitten (1-year old Ragdoll) doesn't do anything WHILE i'm in the shower. She's probably not even in the room. But, as soon as the water stops, she comes in, and meows at me about ten times as i'm drying off. Every time. My shower curtain is transparent, so it's not as if she misses me or doesn't know where I am. She doesn't even care that I'm in the shower until i finish.... Bizarre creatures. She doesn't meow at me when I leave the apartment and return. That's a different behavior — she rolls around on her back....